How to change background-color from search autocomplete onmouseover? Magento2
I want to change the background-color from the input field, that works. Also for the
.search-autocomplete. But if I go onmousover or click at mobile it will be shown with white background and I can't find this parameter.
Could you help?
What I did. --> _extended.less
input[type="text"], textarea {
    background-color : #1f2532 ;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  }

  .search-autocomplete ul:not(:empty) {
    background-color : #1f2532 ;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-top: 0;
}

OK

mouseover or click are showing light gray background from system

Thank you, very much.

I found it.
.search-autocomplete ul:not(:empty), .search-autocomplete ul li:hover, .search-autocomplete ul li.selected, .search-autocomplete ul li   {
    background-color: #1f2532 ;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
   /* border-top: 0; */
}

